# Processing JavaScript before HTML h1 tag

Tags: javascript, html

This HTML file executes alert message and then shows  tag message.
Whereas as per code it should first display  tag message and then show alert prompt.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening that way?.

```
<body>
    <h1>Javascript in HTML</h1>
    <script>
        if(4+3 === 7)
        {    
            alert("you are smart");
        }   
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you see the `h1` displayed is browser-dependent, but on most browsers, it won't be shown while the alert is showing. The reason is that although the `h1` has been added to the DOM, the page hasn't been painted on the screen yet when your code calls `alert`. `alert` is a hangover from the 1990s and should almost never be used in modern web programming. It brings the thread that both JavaScript code and UI painting code share to a complete stop, preventing anything from happening until the alert is dismissed. That's why you don't see the `h1`.

This "stop the world" behavior is being slowly chipped away in modern browsers, however. But again, `alert` should almost never be used in modern web programming.

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesn't repaint the display with every little DOM update, not even during the initial parsing of the HTML document.

It batches changes and repaints periodically.

Your alert happens to trigger between the `h1` being added to the DOM and the browser repainting the display. (It might not always work out that way, even with the exact code you are using.)

JavaScript alerts are blocking and prevent repaints from taking place until they are dismissed.